# C++ - Tray Icon no envia dos notificaciones diferentes

Tags: c++

estoy teniendo un inveniente con las notificaciones del Tray Icon, resulta que cuando yo presiono una tecla se activa la funcion Siwth() y muestra un mensaje, hasta ahi todo ok. Puse un if dentro del ShowMessage para poder mostrar diferentes mensajes dependiendo del valor que se le envie a la funcion ShowMessage. Pero cuando ejecuto la funcion con el segundo valor me muestra el primer mensaje y el segundo.. Yo solo quiero que me muestre el segundo, probe de muchas formas y no encuentro la forma, no se pueden enviar dos mensajes diferentes?

Este es mi codigo

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TryMode.h"
#include "Controller.h"   
#include "TMemory.h"    
#include <ShellAPI.h>
#include "resource.h"
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TrayMode gTrayMode;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TrayMode::Load()
{
    this->TempWindowProc    = NULL;
    this->TempIconProc      = NULL;
    this->InTray            = false;
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TrayMode::SwitchState()
{
    if( IsWindowVisible(pGameWindow) )
    {
        ShowWindow(pGameWindow, SW_HIDE);
        UpdateWindow(pGameWindow);
        this->ShowNotify(true);
        this->ShowMessage(NIIF_INFO,0);
    }
    else
    {
        ShowWindow(pGameWindow, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(pGameWindow);
        this->ShowNotify(false);
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TrayMode::ShowNotify(bool Mode)
{
    this->InTray = Mode;
    NOTIFYICONDATA Icon     = { 0 };
    // ----
    Icon.cbSize             = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    Icon.uID                = TRAYMODE_ICON_ID;
    Icon.uFlags             = NIF_ICON|NIF_MESSAGE|NIF_TIP;
    Icon.hIcon              = (HICON)LoadImage(gController.Instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAIN_ICON), IMAGE_ICON, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
    this->TempIconProc      = Icon.hIcon;
    Icon.hWnd               = pGameWindow;
    Icon.uCallbackMessage   = TRAYMODE_ICON_MESSAGE;
    // ----

    // ----
    if( Mode )
    {
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &Icon);
    }
    else
    {
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &Icon);
    }
    // ----
    DeleteObject(Icon.hIcon);
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TrayMode::ShowMessage(DWORD Type,int Message)
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA Icon     = { 0 };
    // ----
    Icon.cbSize             = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    Icon.uID                = TRAYMODE_ICON_ID;
    Icon.hWnd               = pGameWindow;
    Icon.uFlags             = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_INFO;
    Icon.hIcon              = this->TempIconProc;
    Icon.uCallbackMessage   = TRAYMODE_ICON_MESSAGE;
    Icon.dwInfoFlags        = Type;
    Icon.uTimeout           = 5000;
    // ----
    if(Message == 0){
    strcpy(Icon.szInfo,"Primer mensaje" );
    }
    else if(Message == 1){
    strcpy(Icon.szInfo, "Segundo mensaje" );
    }
    strcpy(Icon.szInfoTitle, "Titulo");
    // ----
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &Icon);
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Si te muestra los dos mensajes es porque estás llamando dos veces a `ShowMessage`. Captura las llamadas a `ShowMessage` (punto de parada en esta función) y analiza la traza de las llamadas... alguna sobrará o estará mal programada

Comment: A lo que voy es porque me muestra los dos mensajes? si yo le puse un if que dependiendo si es 0 o 1 me muestra un valor, la unica forma de que ejecute el valor 0 es cuando se activa la funcion Switch y eso no puede estar pasando ya que si se activara el programa se Maximizaria, ya que el codigo mostrado arriba es para minimizar una ventana presionando una tecla... No se que puede estar pasando :S

Comment: Te muestra los dos mensajes porque estás llamando **dos veces** a la función. En una le pasas el valor `0` y a la otra el valor `1`. Por eso salen los dos mensajes. Por eso te he dicho que depures el programa. Pones un breakpoint en la función y cuando salga el mensaje incorrecto analiza la traza y los valores de los argumentos

Comment: Es un DLL creo que no se puede depurar

Comment: Cree un Switch Case en la funcion Switch y cuando requiere el primer mensaje lo muestra bien, pero cuando llama al segundo caso, llama a los dos, no hay forma de que este llamando a los dos mensajes juntos

Comment: De alguna forma se están realizando dos llamadas. Piensa que te están apareciendo los dos mensajes en dos popups y no un popup con los dos mensajes... Y las DLL [sí se pueden depurar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2017)